# How to use SetState to get data after submit some information in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react'

export default class form extends React.Component{
/// Handle Submit 
handleSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
}
/// handle patientname
handlePatientName(e) {
    this.setState({
        patientname: e.target.value
    })
}
// handle patient disease
handlePatientDisease(e){
    this.setState({
        patientdisease: e.target.value
    })
}
    // handle patient present illness
    handlePatientPresentIllness(e){
    this.setState({
        patientpresentillness: e.target.value
    })
}


render () {
    return (
<form> 
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label> Patient Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="patientname" placeholder="nome do paciente"  OnChange={this.handlePatientName} />

        </li>
        <li>
            <label> Patient Disease 
            <input type="text" name="patientdisease" placeholder="disease"/>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label> Histórico 
            <input type="text" name="patientpresentillness" placeholder="historia do paciente"/>
            </label>
        </li>


        <li>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Submit </button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>
           );
   }
}
```

Objective: Get data from this form and display it in other page(Sidebar.js)
So after submit those informations in that form, I want to get those informations using SetState and display only the patientname in a list.
How do I do that using SetState?

Comment: Is this your actual code? There's some formatting issues (inconsistent indentation) and typos (`OnChange` should be `onChange`).

Comment: why react-native??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code has several problems:

1. Use `onChange` instead of `OnChange`:

   ```
   <input type="text" onChange={this.handlePatientName} />
   ```
2. Your event handlers are not bound to the class instance, so `this` will be undefined in your callback and `this.setState()` will fail. You can solve this by using [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

   ```
   onChange={this.handlePatientName.bind(this)}
   ```

   Or by binding the handlers in your constructor:

   ```
   constructor(){
       this.handlePatientName = this.handlePatientName.bind(this);
   }
   ```

   Or by using [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and defining the handlers as arrow functions:

   ```
   handlePatientName = (e) => {    }
   ```
3. You should name your component `Form` or something other than `form`, since `form` is [used for the HTML form element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-elements).
4. Once all that is done, you are still not exposing the form state to "other pages". To do that you should provide callback props to pass the data outside the component:

   ```
   handlePatientName = (e) => {
       let patientName = e.target.value;
       this.setState({ patientName });
       this.props.onPatientNameChange(patientName);
   }
   ```

   Now from a parent page you can capture the changes:

   ```
   class Parent extends React.Component {
       handlePatientNameChange = (patientName) => {
           console.log("Patient name changed to:", patientName);
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <Form onPatientNameChange={this.handlePatientNameChange} />
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok. I am still not able to do that. Could you see my project on Github and help me out? I am just in the beginning of my ReactJs Journey.